# e.force:navigateToURL

Tags: lightning, url, redirect

I want to send list of selected record Id's from a Lightning component to a visual force page.

Is there any limit on length of url parameters when I use e.force:navigateToURL event and append record id's the url, for this purpose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1.I would recommend you to look at window,postmessage method, it is the recommend secure way to communicate between lightning components and visualforce pages.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html

2) IF you decide to use navigatetoURL and pass it as url params as you guessed, you will have to deal with url limitations, as far as i can know the url limit is set by browsers 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

2) Also  lightning will base64encode your params and append it as a #XXXXXXX value in your url. Anyone who wants to know what is going behind scenes, all they have to do is to use a base64decoder (https://www.base64decode.org/) and convert the # to reveal all the param data.

eG:

```
({
    gotoURL : function (component, event, helper) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        var str= 'abscdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd';
        urlEvent.setParams({
            "url": "https://praowin-dev-ed--c.gus.visual.force.com/apex/testpage?relatedId="+str
        });
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Resulting url from the above component:

https://praowin-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJvbmU6YWxvaGFQYWdlIiwiYXR0cmlidXRlcyI6eyJhZGRyZXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcmFvd2luLWRldi1lZC0tYy5ndXMudmlzdWFsLmZvcmNlLmNvbS9hcGV4L3Rlc3RwYWdlP3JlbGF0ZWRJZD1hYnNjZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGRkZGQifX0%3D

[image]